# Apache POI: XWPFDocument How copy text with comments from one doc to another

Tags: java, apache-poi, comments, docx

Apache poi version: 4.0

I have 2 docs (docx) with comments and formatting.

How can i copy all text (with comments) from first to second?

As i read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44491860/how-to-add-comment-by-apache-poi) we couldn't write comments.xml section by XWPFDocument - it's open comments section only for read.

When i copied one document to second [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10208097/how-to-copy-a-paragraph-of-docx-to-another-docx-withjava-and-retain-the-style):

```
private void copyDoc(XWPFDocument to_document, XWPFDocument from_document) {
    for (IBodyElement bodyElement : to_document.getBodyElements()) {
        BodyElementType elementType = bodyElement.getElementType();

        if (elementType.equals(BodyElementType.PARAGRAPH)) {
             ...
        } else if (elementType.equals(BodyElementType.TABLE)) {
             ...
        }
    }
}
```

i take paragraphs and runs with comment sections, but i don't have their comments in comments.xml of destination file.

So my file is corrupted and opening with errors ("where is no comments for some notice" style), where i have red sections of broken comments.

Is there a way to correct copying all comments to one doc file?

--- UPDATED ---

I used [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50875781/how-to-manipulate-content-of-a-comment-with-apache-poi) to copy comments, but i have some problems.

At first, i tried to take all paragraphs from source files, and all comments by @axel-richter method. But in result doc, where i have comments from 2 files, some of them have same id.

And if MS-Word open file without problems - all comments are correct, LibreOffice write each same-id comments as one.

For example:

- comment from 1.docx with id 1 and text "some comment 1"
- comment from 2.docx with id 1 and text "some comment 2"

Result:

- "Some text from 1.docx from resulting docx" <- with comment "some comment 1 some comment 2"
- "Some text from 2.docx from resulting docx" <- with comment "some comment 1 some comment 2"

When, i rewrite copying of paragraphs and made slide (+10) for comment_id.

```
CTP paragraph_object = insert_paragraph.getCTP();

if (!paragraph_object.getCommentRangeStartList().isEmpty()) {
    CTMarkupRange comment_start = paragraph_object.getCommentRangeStartArray(0);
    BigInteger current_comment_id = comment_start.getId();
    BigInteger new_comment_id = current_comment_id.add(slide);

    comment_start.setId(new_comment_id);
    paragraph_object.getCommentRangeEndArray(0).setId(new_comment_id);
}
```

But from paragraph i cannot change commentReference and my new result docx opened by MS-Word with mistakes and broken inserted comments.

In comments.xml and document.xml of word file i have all new comments with new id (in comments.xml) and correct commentStart/End (in document.xml).

But commentReference remained old, and i have no idea how i can change it  and don't know will it help me