# How to copy all content of a docx file to a new one?

Tags: java, spring-boot, ms-word, apache-poi, thymeleaf

I'm working on a spring boot project using thymeleaf
I need to create a Word file (.docx) based on an existing one (as a template) that contains styles, tables, images... , and also I need to modify and customize some lines at the same time.
I checked some codes and answers about the Apache POI Library but nothing works for my case.

Any ideas PLEASE!
Thanks and regards

---

I solved my problem using this code :

```
public void wordFileCreator() throws IOException
    {
            String filename = "Template.docx";
            try {

                XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(new FileInputStream(filename)));
                List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphList = doc.getParagraphs();
                for (XWPFParagraph para : paragraphList) {
                    for (XWPFRun run : para.getRuns()) {
                        String text = run.text();
                        if(text.contains("StringToReplace")){
                            text = text.replace("StringToReplace", "newVal");
                            run.setText(text, 0);
                        }
                    }
                }
                doc.write(new FileOutputStream("newFile.docx"));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

Comment: what did you try? share it and tell us whats wrong with it and why it didn't work

Comment: I tried to use the code given in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/25375809/9770112 but, it gives an error in the copyStyle method after running the code, and it generate an empty file.

Comment: Why trying copying from one `Word` file to another? Why not simply opening the template as a `XWPFDocument`, changing what is needed in that document and then writing the `XWPFDocument` into another file so the template stays unchanged?

Comment: Thanks for replying .. Yeah it's a great idea and it seems to be easier, but how I can make changes on the file in specific places ?

Comment: And I should conserve the style of document either